# Setup Nginx with existing Magento install

Tags: magento, nginx, configuration

I'm trying to setup Nginx to evaluate its potential running Mangento on a multistore plateform.

After disabling apache, and enabling Nginx (correctly installed and configured), running the website leads to the Magento installation page (insted of the store), with the following error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in
>   /home/www/alpha/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php on line
>   71

Looks like the `getStore()` method is failing.

I thought it was because the MAGE_RUN_CODE was not setup properly, so I added this to my domain config file :

```
fastcgi_param MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE my_website_code;
```

Finaly, the error is still there and I cannot access the desired store.

Any help / tips are warmly welcome.

Regards
Sorcy

Comment: I'm not sure how adding fastcgi_params would help. If this was working as is in Apache and only stopped working with nginx, have you doublec-hecked the [nginx configuration for magento](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)?

Comment: I did this because in Apache2, I used VirtualHosts directives to specify wich website leads to what webstore (using MageRunCode).

Comment: So use virtualhosts in nginx: different server => different location and root...

Comment: Previously with Apache2, I used VirtualHosts to identify a request by the server_name (ex : www.store1.com). Root folder was always the same path to Magento install. I only had to change the MageRunCode value, to forward the request to the correct Website / webstore.

Now, I created 1 single file in site-available, redirecting to my Magento's folder, with the correct MageRunCode.

I wonder if the problem doesn't come from the rewriting or from the connexion to DB...

Comment: Looks like the MageRunCode param is not the problem 'cause it's being fowareded correctly.